# Entity Framework loading some, none or all navigation properties dynamically

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Looking at this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager) I can see that you can load multiple navigation entities using the following syntax:

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    var userDocs = context.UserDocuments
        .Include(userDoc => userDoc.Role.User)            
        .ToList();
}
```

This will give me `Role` and `User` navigation properties hung off my `UserDocument` object, however if I want to use the string overload of Include, how might I construct the code to handle multiple includes?

This does not work:

```
return await ctx.UserDocuments.Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
.Include("Role.User").ToList();
```

I am trying to do it this way as my methods may want some, all or no navigation properties returned depending on the calling code. My intention is to add a string array to the repository method which will build any required navigation properties accordingly. If this is the wrong approach, does anyone have another recommendation, I'm wondering if lazy loading would be a more elegant solution...?

**Edit**

This is the Entity which has nav props:

```
public partial class UserDocument
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public Guid UserId { get; set; }
  public int RoleId { get; set; }
  public int AccountId { get; set; }
     
  public virtual Role Role { get; set; } = null!;
  public virtual User User { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Comment: Role.User are two differents entities or one?

Comment: Two different entities or navigation properties for my UserDocument object

Comment: i have already answered your question. Please vote it if it's correct and help you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
public async Task<List<UserDocument>> MyMethod(List<string> propertiesToInclude)
{
    IQueryable<UserDocument> currentQuery = _context.UserDocuments.Where(x => x.UserId == userId);
    
    foreach(var property in propertiesToInclude)
    {
        currentQuery = currentQuery.Include(property);
    }
    return await currentQuery.ToListAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `Include(String)` method, you don't need to include the lambda to specify the property path.

Instead of doing `.Include(x => "Role.User")`, try `.Include("Role.User")`

Comment: Sorry, i already tried that, have edited the question to reflect, this doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must told us what is "Role.User"?
We cannot answer you if we don't know excactly what you wrote.

So, now we are know that are two differents entities you can do this one

```
var userDocs = await context.UserDocuments
    .Include(x => x.Role)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.User) 
    .ToListAsync();
```

I hope this one helps you. :)

Comment: I've put the model into the question, I already know how to do includes using the lamda expression, the question was how can you do multiple includes using the string overload.

Comment: Strongly type way is better. 
strings types aren't good for refactoring.
So, i recommended to use strongly types.

Comment: Ok so how would you pass the specified includes into this method?

Comment: Something like that.

return await ctx.UserDocuments
.Include(x => x.Role)
.ThenInclude(x => x.User)
.Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
.ToListAsync();